# Как влияет на безопасность хранение названий всех используемых классов в БД?

Tags: безопасность, php, mysql

Нужен совет.
Как влияет на безопасность хранение названий основных используемых классов в БД?
Данные классы и таблица используется в админской части сайта.

Comment: Никак / косвенно отрицательно. Каким образом это вообще от чего-то может защитить?

Comment: Защитить не сможет, повредить может. За сим и спрашиваю, т.к. у самого опыта  недостаточно, чтобы оценить возможные угрозы.

Comment: @hcuser К примеру, в CMF MODx php-код приложения (snippets) хранится в БД для удобной правки из админки. Опционально доступно использования статичных php-файлов, но по умолчанию в БД. Вот пример посерьёзнее: [реализация RBAC в Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rbac/DbManager.php#L249). Сериализованные объекты Rule и Permission хранятся в БД. Такова особенность реализации. Минусом такого подхода может оказаться деградация Вашего кода. К примеру, решили изменить название класса/неймспейса - будьте добры поправить в БД. Забывчивость можно отловить unit-тестированием.

Comment: Спасибо, друг. Как я понимаю, особого криминала в подобном подходе нет. Вопрос только в организации и обслуживания кода, ну это уже дело техники. Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ с примерами.

Comment: @hcuser Да не за что. Тогда с вашего позволения добавлю свой комментарий в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

К примеру, в [CMF MODx](http://modx.com/) php-код приложения (snippets) хранится в БД для удобной правки из админки. Опционально доступно использования статичных php-файлов, но по умолчанию в БД. Вот пример посерьёзнее: [реализация RBAC в Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rbac/DbManager.php#L249). Сериализованные объекты Rule и Permission хранятся в БД. Такова особенность реализации. Минусом такого подхода может оказаться деградация Вашего кода. К примеру, решили изменить название класса/неймспейса - будьте добры поправить в БД. Забывчивость можно отловить unit-тестированием.